# SPUtility Error page isn't display

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I try to made a workflow in Visual Studio 2010 to Sharepoint 2010 and i need send a error message to user.
My code:

```
  private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      var item = workflowsProperties.Item;
    foreach(String att in item.Attachments)
 {
        if (att.EndWith(...))
        {
        SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("This extension is not permited!");
        }
        else
        {
        ...
        }
}
```

I have the workflow status "completed".
But redirect to the Error page doesn't happen.
But when the item is already created and the workflow is activated manually, it work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if this is executing on itemcreated...is it possible the code is firing before the attachments are added?...maybe attachments count is zero?

Comment: look, my application reaches SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage ("This extension is not allowed!"); but it does not do anything, I even put him in a catch; and nothing.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235752/sputility-error-page-isnt-displaying